# Why can't a symbolic link be created in a directory location that is not the current working directory?

Tags: linux, symlink

Creating a test file called `test.txt` and then trying to link to a location in `src` seems to produce an empty file with the name of the target file. However, if I am in the target directory, it works fine.

**Example**

`ln -s test.txt src/test.txt` creates a blank file called `test.txt` in the `src` directory.

However, `cd`ing into `src` and then creating the link works:

`cd src/ && ln -s ../test.txt test.txt` creates a valid link to `test.txt` in `src` called `test.txt`

Comment: Use absolute paths.  That will make it work everywhere

Comment: `ln -s test.txt src/test.txt` creates a link to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target of a symbolic link is a relative path, it's interpreted relative to the directory containing the link, not the directory you were in when you created it. This allows you to move a directory hierarchy that has symbolic link references between directories, and they'll remain valid.

So if you want to use a relative pathname, you need to use `../test.txt` no matter what directory you're in when you create the link.